# Apps Script: GmailApp not defined

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I'm trying to create a Google Apps Script to delete some email in bulk. The code for this doesn't really matter though as the `GMailApp` object isn't defined. I create a new project, add the following code:

```
function main() {
  var threads = GMailApp.search('.....');
}
```

and I just get an error 'ReferenceError: GMailApp is not defined'. Do I have to enable the GMailApp? I thought the point of the app services was that they didn't need an API to be enabled, and that they can just be linked and used.

Any help appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From menu select "Resources" -- "Advanced Google Services" and turn "Gmail API" on.

[image]

Pay attention to write in code **GmailApp**, not GMailApp.

Comment: The GmailApp is different from the Gmail API, the latter being the more traditional Google API. However you are correct that the case was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to avoid typos by getting used to using the "Control-Spacebar" short cut.

When you are in the Apps Script IDE holding control and spacebar at the same time will give you a popup of all the classes and then you just select the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

So in summary, the API object is `GmailAPP`, not `GMailApp`. The autocomplete with ctrl+space should help with problems like these however at some point I had it autocompleting my code so it must have got confused down the line. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

### 2021 Update for the Gmail API (not GmailApp)

If you're in the 2021 and later IDE, it's here:

[image]

Also, note that `Gmail` is different from `GmailApp`. In my experience `Gmail` is more customizable, because you're getting exposed to the Gmail API whereas `GmailApp` is a less-robust collection of methods, but it's simpler to use.